# Is it possible to retrieve in output which predicate in where clause is evaluated true?

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria-api

Is it possibile in a select query that has a where clause with a lot of predicates retrieving in output which one predicate is evaluated true, together with real tuple?

For instance, given this table:

```
Table person
name        age         hair_color
Tom         12          Brown
Bob         27          Black
Sam         20          Red
Ann         15          Blonde
John        30          Blonde
```

An that query:

```
select *
from person
where (age >= 25) or (hair_color = 'Blonde')
```

I would like to have in output something like that:

```
name        age         hair_color      clause_1        clause_2
Bob         27          Black           true            false
Ann         15          Blonde          false           true
John        30          Blonde          true            true
```

What do you suggest to achieve a similar result?

**UPDATE**

Thanks! You answered my question! So It's possible with something like that:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, 
        (age >= 25) as clause_1, 
        (hair_color = 'Blonde') as clause_2
    from test.person as p
) as t
where t.clause_1 or t.clause_2
```

Now I have a related one. If I already have a table predisposed to contain this clause evaluations, for instance 'check_1' and 'check_2'.

```
Table person
name        age         hair_color      check_1     check_2
Tom         12          Brown
Bob         27          Black
Sam         20          Red
Ann         15          Blonde
John        30          Blonde
```

Is there any way to 'temporary' valorize this field during the select query (check_1 = clause_1, check_2 = clause_2)?

```
name        age         hair_color      check_1     check_2
Bob         27          Black           true        false
Ann         15          Blonde          false       true
John        30          Blonde          true        true
```

I ask you because I need it in a Java project in which I use JPA and Criteria API to make typed query, and I would like to get the object 'Person' with 'check' values evaluated in one shot.

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the condition:

```
select *
from (
  select p.*, 
         (age >= 25) as condition_1, 
         (hair_color = 'Blonde') as condition_2
  from person p
) t
where condition_1 or condition_2
```

The above is standard SQL and assumes the DBMS being used support a proper `boolean` data type.

I am not sure though how smart an optimizer would be to push down the condition so this might be slower then the original query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select name, age, hair_color, (age >= 25) AS Clause1, (hair_color like 'Blonde') AS Clause2
from person
where (age >= 25) or (hair_color like 'Blonde')
```

should do the job.

*Side note*: `like` without `%` is strange

Comment: To avoid duplication of the conditions, it can also be written as `select name, age, hair_color, Clause1, Clause2 from (select *, (age >= 25) as Clause1, (hair_color like 'Blonde') as Clause2 from Person) as sub where Clause1 or Clause2`. And a note: some database systems do not allow boolean expressions to be treated as values, they would require something along the lines of `case when (condition) then 1 else 0 end as ClauseN`, and then `where Clause1 <> 0 or Clause2 <> 0`.